CTRL, ALT and shift keys not working except for when typing or using a shortcut,
I'm on mint cinnamon and this is a new error that occured, I tried connecting a different keyboard but it's to no avail, set the keyboard configs back to default and still no recognition outside of shortcuts and typing. (if it's any use, my "Copy a screenshot of an area to clipboard" also stopped working, everything works fine really it just doesn't copy the screenshot making it entirely useless.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried running Mint from USB? If that works, then save data, reinstall Mint, then restore data.

As much as I wish that would fix it, I'm unable to do anything related to reinstalling the ISO.
